# Saving Python turtle graphics as an animated .gif?

Tags: image, python-3.x, graphics, save

I have made several programs in Python that have output showing up as a window called Python Turtle Graphics.

I want to save these files as .gifs for internet purposes.

Can the output of a Python program using the turtle library be saved as an animated .gif?

Comment: find image lib that support GIF for your platform and add frame on each repaint of your window. Other option is to use grabber app that selects part of desktop and saves it as GIF (there are some out there those I tried had free trials for 30 days and had a message over the GIF feed but works.

Comment: If you're using Mac OSX, I've just written up [how to create an animated GIF using just Python turtle and Preview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41319971/is-there-a-way-to-save-turtles-drawing-as-an-animated-gif/41353016#41353016)

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way would be a screen recording app.
Something like [GifCam](http://blog.bahraniapps.com/gifcam/) could be a nice easy solution.
Alternatively you could use something like [BB Flashback recorder](https://www.flashbackrecorder.com/) to record a video and then convert to a gif.  The advantage here would be you can also capture the moue interactions if there are any.

Comment: Author talking about programmatic way of creating gif image. It is an programmers resource at least.

Comment: Their question doesn't say anything about a programmatic way to get a gif.  Also, using just the turtle library it can't be done. You would need additional libraries or external processing.     With only the turtle library you could save single frames of the drawing as an image and then composite them into a gif afterwards.