# How can I execute a Python Turtle script from my webhost?

Tags: python, indexing, web, turtle-graphics

I'd like this Python script to run through my webhost/domain. That way maybe I can put a hyperlink on my index that leads to this for a little display?

I would like this to be played in the tab

```
import turtle
  bob = turtle.Pen() 
  for i in range(700):
    bob.forward(i)
    bob.left(80)
    bob.forward(50)
    bob.right(i)
    bob.back(50)
    bob.left(i)
```

Comment: You are expecting this to run and draw in your browser?

Comment: Yeah from my website host. Is it possible?

Comment: No, that's not going to run in your browser and draw anything, I'm afraid. Google around for 'javascript turtle graphics' for some libraries that would let you do something similar but in-browser.

Comment: Ah alrighty thanks heaps anyway!

Comment: You can [make an animated gif](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41353016/5771269) that's essentially a tiny video of what your turtle program does.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question but since someone else just found it and posted a response, maybe others are searching for this functionality as well.

If you are just looking to share your turtle code with others and show its output, Repl.it can do this for you.

Live demo of your code [here](https://repl.it/repls/RobustRoundedAddin#main.py)