# How do I draw this shape in Turtle?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

[image]

I got a challenge in a learning group today to draw this shape in python turtle library.

I cannot figure out a way to express the geometrical solution to find the angles to turn and the size of the line I need.

Can you please tell me how to draw the first polygon alone? I already know how to make the pattern.

I am in fifth grade. So please give me a solution that I can understand.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Tes. Can you clarify what you mean by "drawing the first polygon alone"? Are you asking how to draw for example this part https://i.imgur.com/H2wX19n.png or this part https://i.imgur.com/KcdEpON.png or another part?

Comment: You can find some information in Wikipedia on this [kite polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kite_(geometry)) shape.

Answer (score 8):

Here is the solution I came up with. It is based on this diagram:

[image]

### Math background

My solution uses "trigonometry", which is a method for calculating the length of one side of a triangle from the length of another side and the angles of the triangle. This is advanced math which I would expect to be taught maybe in 9th or 10th grade. I do not expect someone in 5th grade to know trigonometry. Also I cannot explain every detail of trigonometry, because I would have to write a lot and I do not think I have the teaching skills to make it clear. I would recommend you to look at for example this  video to learn about the method:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5tp74g4N8EY

You could also ask your teacher for more information, or research about it on the internet on your own.

### Step 1: Calculating the angles

We can do this without trigonometry.

First, we see there is a "pentagon" (5-sided polygon) in the middle. I want to know the inner angle of a corner in this "pentagon". I call this angle `X`:

[image]

How can we calculate the angle `X`? We first remember that the sum of the inner angles in a triangle is `180°`. We see that we can divide a 5-sides polygon into `5-2` triangles like this:

[image]

The sum of the inner angle of each of these `5-2` triangles is `180°`. So for the whole 5-sided polygon, the sum of the inner angles is `180° * (5-2)`. Since all angles have the same size, each angle is `180°*(5-2) / 5 = 108°`. So we have `X = 108°`.

The angle on the other side is the same as `X`. This allows us the calculate the angle between the two `X`. I will call this angle `Y`:

[image]

Since a full circle is `360°`, we know that `360° = 2*X + 2*Y`. Therefore, `Y = (360° - 2*X) / 2`. We know that `X = 108°`, so we get `Y = 72°`.

Next, we see there is a triangle containing the `Y` angle. I want to know the angle `Z` at the other corner of the triangle:

[image]

The inner angles of a triangle sum up to `180°*(3-2) = 180°`. Therefore, we know that `180° = 2*Y + Z`, so `Z = 180° - 2*Y`. We know that `Y = 72°`, so we get `Z = 36°`.

We will use the angle `Z` a lot. You can see that every corner of the green star has angle `Z`. The blue star is the same as the green star except it is rotated, so all blue corners also have angle `Z`. The corners of the red star are twice as wide as the corners of the green and blue stars, so the corners of the red star have the angle `2*Z`.

### Step 2: Calculating the lengths

First, we observe that all outer corners are on a circle. We call the radius of this circle `R`. We do not have to calculate `R`. Instead, we can take any value we want for `R`. We will always get the same shape but in different sizes. We could call `R` a "parameter" of the shape.

[image]

Given some value for `R`, I want to know the following lengths:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

### Calculating `A`:

We start with `A`. We can see the following triangle:

[image]

The long side of the triangle is our radius `R`. The other side has length `A/2` and we do not care about the third side. The angle in the right-most corner is `Z/2` (with `Z = 36°` being the angle we calculated in the previous section). The angle `S` is a right-angle, so `S = 90°`. We can calculate the third angle `T` because we know that the inner angles of a triangle sum up to `180°`. Therefore, `180° = S + Z/2 + T`. Solving for `T`, we get `T = 180° - S - Z/2 = 180° - 90° - 36°/2 = 72°`.

Next, we use trigonometry to calculate `A/2`. Trigonometry teaches us that `A/2 = R * sin(T)`. Putting in the formula for `T`, we get `A/2 = R * sin(72°)`. Solving for `A`, we get `A = 2*R*sin(72°)`.

If you pick some value for `R`, for example `R = 100`, you can now calculate `A` with this formula. You would need a calculator for `sin(72°)`, because it would be extremely difficult to calculate this in your head. Putting `sin(72)` into my calculator gives me `0.951056516`. So for our choice `R = 100`, we know that `A = 2 * R * sin(72°) = 2 * 100 * 0.951056516 = 190.211303259`.

### Calculating `B`:

We use the same technique to find a formula for `B`. We see the following triangle:

[image]

So the bottom side is the length of our radius `R`. The right side is `B/2`. We do not care about the third side. The right-most angle is three times `Z/2`. The angle `S` is a right-angle, so we have `S = 90°`. We can calculate the remaining angle `T` with `180° = S + T + 3*Z/2`. Solving for `T`, we get `T = 180° - S - 3*Z/2 = 180° - 90° - 3*36°/2 = 36°`. Ok so `T = Z`, we could have also seen this from the picture, but now we have calculated it anyways.

Using trigonometry, we know that `B/2 = R * sin(T)`, so we get the formula `B = 2 * R * sin(36°)` to calculate `B` for some choice of `R`.

### Calculating `C`:

We see the following triangle:

[image]

So the bottom side has length `A/2` and the top side has length `B`. We already have formulas for both of these sides. The third side is `C`, for which we want to find a formula. The right-most angle is `Z`. The angle `S` is a right-angle, so `S = 90°`. The top-most angle is three times `Z/2`.

Using trigonometry, we get `C = sin(Z) * B`.

### Calculating `D`:

We see the following triangle:

[image]

We already have a formula for `C`. We want to find a formula for `D`. The top-most angle is `Z/2` (I could not fit the text into the triangle). The bottom-left angle `S` is a right-angle.

Using trigonometry, we know that `D = tan(Z/2) * C`. The `tan` function is similar to the `sin` from the previous formulas. You can again put it into your calculator to compute the value, so for `Z = 36°`, I can put `tan(36/2)` into my calculator and it gives me `0.324919696`.

### Calculating `E`:

Ok this is easy, `E = 2*D`.

Halfway done already!

### Calculating `F`:

This is similar to `A` and `B`:

[image]

We want to find a formula for `F`. The top side has length `F/2`. The bottom side has the length of our radius `R`. The right-most corner has angle `Z`. `S` is a right-angle. We can calculate `T = 180° - S - Z = 180° - 90° - Z = 90° - Z`.

Using trigonometry, we get `F/2 = R * sin(T)`. Putting in the formula for `T` gives us `F/2 = R*sin(90° - Z)`. Solving for `F` gives us `F = 2*R*sin(90°-Z)`.

### Calculating `G`:

We see the following triangle:

[image]

The top side has length `F`, we already know a formula for it. The right side has length `G`, we want to find a formula for it. We do not care about the bottom side. The left-most corner has angle `Z/2`. The right-most corner has angle `2*Z`. The bottom corner has angle `S`, which is a right-angle, so `S = 90°`. It was not immediately obvious to me that the red line and the green line are perfectly perpendicular to each other so that `S` really is a right-angle, but you can verify this by using the formula for the inner angles of a triangle, which gives you `180° = Z/2 + 2*Z + S`. Solving for `S` gives us `S = 180° - Z/2 - 2*Z`. Using `Z = 36°`, we get `S = 180° - 36°/2 - 2* 36° = 90°`.

Using trigonometry, we get `G = F * sin(Z/2)`.

### Calculating `H`:

We see the following triangle:

[image]

The right side has length `G`, we already have formula for that. The bottom side has length `H`, we want to find a formula for that. We do not care about the third side. The top corner has angle `Z`, the bottom-right corner has angle `S`. We already know that `S` is a right-angle from the last section.

Using trigonometry, we get `H = G * tan(Z)`.

### Calculating `I`:

This is easy, `I` is on the same line as `A`. We can see that `A` can be divided into `A = I + H + E + H + I`. We can simplify this to `A = 2*I + 2*H + E`. Solving for `I` gives us `I = (A - 2*H - E)/2`.

### Calculating `J`:

Again this is easy, `J` is on the same line as `F`. We can see that `F` can be divided into `F = G + J + G`. We can simplify that to `F = 2*G + J`. Solving for `J` gives us `J = F - 2*G`.

### Writing the Python program

We now have formulas for all the lines we were interested in! We can now put these into a Python program to draw the picture.

Python gives you helper functions for computing `sin` and `tan`. They are contained in the `math` module. So you would add `import math` to the top of your program, and then you can use `math.sin(...)` and `math.tan(...)` in your program. However, there is one problem: These Python functions do not use degrees to measure angles. Instead they use a different unit called "radians". Fortunately, it is easy to convert between degrees and radians: In degrees a full circle is `360°`. In radians, a full circle is `2*pi`, where `pi` is a special constant that is approximately `3.14159265359...`. Therefore, we can convert an angle that is measured in degrees into an angle that is measured in radians, by dividing the angle by `360°` and then multiplying it by `2*pi`. We can write the following helper functions in Python:

```py
import math

def degree_to_radians(angle_in_degrees):
  full_circle_in_degrees = 360
  full_circle_in_radians = 2 * math.pi

  angle_in_radians = angle_in_degrees / full_circle_in_degrees * full_circle_in_radians

  return angle_in_radians

def sin_from_degrees(angle_in_degrees):
  angle_in_radians = degree_to_radians(angle_in_degrees)
  return math.sin(angle_in_radians)

def tan_from_degrees(angle_in_degrees):
  angle_in_radians = degree_to_radians(angle_in_degrees)
  return math.tan(angle_in_radians)
```

We can now use our functions `sin_from_degrees` and `tan_from_degrees` to compute `sin` and `tan` from angles measured in degrees.

Putting it all together:

```py
from turtle import *

import math

# Functions to calculate sin and tan ###########################################

def degree_to_radians(angle_in_degrees):
  full_circle_in_degrees = 360
  full_circle_in_radians = 2 * math.pi

  angle_in_radians = angle_in_degrees / full_circle_in_degrees * full_circle_in_radians

  return angle_in_radians

def sin_from_degrees(angle_in_degrees):
  angle_in_radians = degree_to_radians(angle_in_degrees)
  return math.sin(angle_in_radians)

def tan_from_degrees(angle_in_degrees):
  angle_in_radians = degree_to_radians(angle_in_degrees)
  return math.tan(angle_in_radians)

# Functions to calculate the angles ############################################

def get_X():
  num_corners = 5
  return (num_corners-2)*180 / num_corners

def get_Y():
  return (360 - 2*get_X()) / 2

def get_Z():
  return 180 - 2*get_Y()

# Functions to calculate the lengths ###########################################

def get_A(radius):
  Z = get_Z()
  return 2 * radius * sin_from_degrees(90 - Z/2)

def get_B(radius):
  Z = get_Z()
  return 2 * radius * sin_from_degrees(90 - 3*Z/2)

def get_C(radius):
  Z = get_Z()
  return sin_from_degrees(Z) * get_B(radius)

def get_D(radius):
  Z = get_Z()
  return tan_from_degrees(Z/2) * get_C(radius)

def get_E(radius):
  return 2 * get_D(radius)

def get_F(radius):
  Z = get_Z()
  return 2 * radius * sin_from_degrees(90 - Z)

def get_G(radius):
  Z = get_Z()
  return get_F(radius) * sin_from_degrees(Z/2)

def get_H(radius):
  Z = get_Z()
  return get_G(radius) * tan_from_degrees(Z)

def get_I(radius):
  A = get_A(radius)
  E = get_E(radius)
  H = get_H(radius)
  return (A - E - 2*H) / 2

def get_J(radius):
  F = get_F(radius)
  G = get_G(radius)
  return F - 2*G

# Functions to draw the stars ##################################################

def back_to_center():
  penup()
  goto(0, 0)
  setheading(0)
  pendown()

def draw_small_star(radius):
  penup()
  forward(radius)
  pendown()

  Z = get_Z()

  left(180)
  right(Z/2)

  E = get_E(radius)
  H = get_H(radius)
  I = get_I(radius)

  for i in range(0,5):
    penup()
    forward(I)

    pendown()
    forward(H)

    penup()
    forward(E)

    pendown()
    forward(H)

    penup()
    forward(I)

    left(180)
    right(Z)

  back_to_center()

def draw_green_star(radius):
  pencolor('green')
  draw_small_star(radius)

def draw_blue_star(radius):
  pencolor('blue')

  Z = get_Z()
  left(Z)

  draw_small_star(radius)

def draw_red_star(radius):
  pencolor('red')

  Z = get_Z()

  penup()
  forward(radius)
  pendown()

  left(180)
  right(Z)

  G = get_G(radius)
  J = get_J(radius)

  for i in range(0,10):
    pendown()
    forward(G)

    penup()
    forward(J)

    pendown()
    forward(G)

    left(180)
    right(2*Z)

  back_to_center()

def draw_shape(radius):
  draw_green_star(radius)
  draw_blue_star(radius)
  draw_red_star(radius)

radius = 400
draw_shape(radius)
done()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Please tell me, how can I post a turtle animation like you did?

Comment: I didn't find an automatic way to do it (there probably is), so I used a screen-recording program (simplescreenrecorder on Linux) to record an mp4 of the window and then converted the mp4 to gif using ffmpeg.

Comment: @AnnZen, if you use a Mac, then see [Make an animated GIF from Python turtle using Preview on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41353016/5771269) but be warned that the latest OSX breaks some of the steps since this was a useful thing to be able to do.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't use mac.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a different solution.  It's based on a kite polygon where the upper portion is a pair of 3-4-5 right triangles and the lower portion is a pair of 8-15-17 right triangles:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

KITES = 10
RADIUS = 100

def kite(t):
    t.right(37)
    t.forward(100)
    t.right(81)
    t.forward(170)

    t.right(124)

    t.forward(170)
    t.right(81)
    t.forward(100)
    t.right(37)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.penup()
turtle.sety(-RADIUS)

for _ in range(KITES):
    turtle.circle(RADIUS, extent=180/KITES)
    turtle.pendown()

    kite(turtle)

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.circle(RADIUS, extent=180/KITES)

turtle.hideturtle()

screen = Screen()
screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

(Yes, I'm obsessed with this puzzle.)  I was sufficiently impressed by the brevity of @AnnZen's solution, I decided to see if I could come up with an even shorter one.  The only unique structure in this polygon is the side of the kite:

[image]

So the problem becomes drawing ten of these in a circular fashion, and then reversing the code to draw them again in the opposite direction:

```
from turtle import *

for _ in range(2):
    for _ in range(10):
        fd(105)
        lt(90)
        fd(76.5)
        pu()
        bk(153)
        rt(54)
        pd()

    lt(72)
    lt, rt = rt, lt

done()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## My Short code:

```
from turtle import *
for f, t in [(0,-72),(71,108),(71,0)]*10+[(29,90),(73,72),(73,90),(29,72)]*10:fd(f),rt(t)
```

Comment: Ann, my eyeballing of this nifty solution suggests that if you change your second array to instead be `[(28.9, 90), (72.6, 72), (72.6, 90), (28.9, 72)]` you'll get a cleaner result.

Comment: Cool, if you eyeballed it. Did you really?

Comment: Yes, I broke it into two loops for the two arrays, lifted the pen and instead printed dots on each iteration, two colors for the two loops.  Then I could see where the subset of dots from the two loops that should overlap didn't, and by how much.  Tweaking individual numbers up and down, I was able to get them to align.  I rarely "do the math".

Answer (score 1):

## Here's the solution:

```
import turtle
#turtle.tracer(0)
a = turtle.Turtle()
for _ in range(10):
    a.forward(100)
    a.right(90)
    a.forward(73)
    a.right(72)
    a.forward(73)
    a.backward(73)
    a.right(108)
    a.forward(73)
    a.right(90)
    a.penup()
    a.forward(100)
    a.pendown()
    a.forward(100)
    a.right(108)
#turtle.update()
```

[image: Result:]

Comment: Your solution is much shorter than mine :) Did you calculate the values by hand?

Comment: Yes, measured some angles and did some calculations.

Comment: Your three step sequence: `a.left(180); a.forward(73); a.left(72)` can be shortened to the two step sequence: `a.backward(73); a.right(108)` and the turn: `a.left(252)` can also be written: `a.right(108)`

Comment: You're right, I didn't realize it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at a yet another approach to drawing this shape.  We'll start with the same diagram as @f9c69e9781fa194211448473495534

[image]

Using a ruler (1" = 100px) and protractor on the OP's original image, we can approximate this diagram with very simple code:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.penup()  # center on the screen
turtle.setposition(-170, -125)
turtle.pendown()

for _ in range(10):
    turtle.forward(340)
    turtle.left(126)
    turtle.forward(400)
    turtle.left(126)

screen = Screen()
screen.exitonclick()
```

This is equivalent to drawing with a pencil and not lifting it nor overdrawing (backing up) on any line.

To make the shape we want pop out, we divide the two lines that we draw above into *segments* that are thinner and thicker.  The first line breaks into three segments and the second into five:

[image]

To do this, we simply break the `forward()` calls in our loop into wide and narrow segments:

```
for _ in range(10):
    turtle.width(4)
    turtle.forward(105)
    turtle.width(1)
    turtle.forward(130)
    turtle.width(4)
    turtle.forward(105)

    turtle.left(126)

    turtle.width(1)
    turtle.forward(76.5)
    turtle.width(4)
    turtle.forward(76.5)
    turtle.width(1)
    turtle.forward(94)
    turtle.width(4)
    turtle.forward(76.5)
    turtle.width(1)
    turtle.forward(76.5)

    turtle.left(126)
```

Finally, we replace the thickness changes with lifting and lowering the pen:

[image]

Which is simply a matter of replacing the `width()` calls with `penup()` and `pendown()`:

```
for _ in range(10):
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.forward(105)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(130)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.forward(105)

    turtle.left(126)

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(76.5)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.forward(76.5)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(94)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.forward(76.5)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(76.5)

    turtle.left(126)
```