# exporting python turtle drawing to video

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, video-capture, python-turtle

Is there a way to export a python turtle drawing to a video?
The video should contain the real-time drawing process.

In particular I'm not interested in a screen-recording workaround, but a solution that would work in a headless system like a cloud environment.

Here's an example of a turtle drawing

```
import turtle 
tr = turtle.Turtle()
rad = 80
tr.circle(rad)
turtle.done()
```

Comment: If a gif can satisfy your needs you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41319971/is-there-a-way-to-save-turtles-drawing-as-an-animated-gif) there are ways to save frames using tkinter

Comment: I don't know a way, but if you are really desperate try using a screen recorder such as OBS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to save turtle's drawing as an animated GIF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41319971/is-there-a-way-to-save-turtles-drawing-as-an-animated-gif). Once to snapshot frames, then creating an mp4 or other video format is about the same as creating a gif.

Answer (score 0):

You can use turtle.getcanvas().postscript(file=output_file) [link](https://discuss.python.org/t/how-turtle-can-save-the-whole-canvas-to-eps-file-if-the-screen-size-is-bigger-than-my-monitor-screen-size/12823) to save images and concatenate them to video using moviepy.editor.ImageSequenceClip [link](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/getting_started/videoclips.html)